# Why AWT frame's text field is not appearing?

Tags: java, awt, frame

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class example3 extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
TextField t;
Button b;
    example3()
    {
        t = new TextField();
        t.setBounds(20,20,170,20);
        add(t);

        b = new Button("click me");
        b.setBounds(100,120,80,30);
        add(b);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(300,300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        t.setText("welcome");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        example3 obj = new example3();
    }
}
```

Initially I added a text field to the the frame object and I created a button also and added this to frame object but I am not getting correct output.

When I executed this program **the text field does not appear.** Why?

I got output like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1YcJ.png)

Comment: What do you think there point 0, 0 on a frame is? So ... don't you think that 20, 20 is a rather bad placement on there? Also, you can see parts of the textfield in your picture.

Comment: I'd say your problem starts with `setLayout(null);`, but then I'd also say using AWT is probably a bad place to start.  I'd suggest starting with [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) but it might better to start with JavaFX instead

Comment: Stay away from AWT. Use Swing.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest only one change in line number 11, that **increase the x-coordinate and y-coordinate value of setBounds** as per your requirement because your code is working but that field is not at a visible location.

as example:-
your code:-         t.setBounds(20,20,170,20);
after changing:-    t.setBounds(50,50,170,20);

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class example3 extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
TextField t;
Button b;
    example3()
    {
        t = new TextField();

        
       // t.setBounds(20,20,170,20);
       //Changes has been done,here.
       t.setBounds(50,50,170,20);
        add(t);



        

        b = new Button("click me");
        b.setBounds(100,120,80,30);
        add(b);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(300,300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        t.setText("welcome");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        example3 obj = new example3();
    }
}
```

I hope, it will be helpful.